# What can be done when AKS node autoscaling is not keeping up with demand?

Tags: azure, load-testing, azure-aks, autoscaling

I have an AKS cluster running with a minimum of 5 nodes and a maximum of 150 using the Standard_D4S_v3 tier and 3 workloads + traefik as a reverse proxy.
Currently I am trying to run a loadtest to verify that my application is able to stay stable and serve the incoming load for a production based environment.
My app was alread running fine on ServiceFabric, but I decided to switch to Kubernetes due to various reasons. On ServiceFabric I did not really use any autoscaling feature due to it not functioning correctly.
Now I am facing smilar issues with AKS where my pods are scaling with HPA but the cluster nodes can't keep up and many of my new pods are staying in pending state for multiple minutes (15min+).

Is there maybe an option to tell AKS to scale nodes with a certain percentage when the autoscaling is triggered? I found this documentation on aks autoscaling https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-autoscaler#using-the-autoscaler-profile but there doesn't seem to be options that increase scaling speed/amount.

I also saw some workarounds (with buffer/pause-pods which is kind of an overprovisioning and I don't really want to do that since my goal is to save costs when the load is low:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1041334/how-can-i-autoscale-my-azure-kubernetes-nodepool-before-resources-run-out

Comment: "can't keep up", so the cluster scale up but not enough to handle your workload, right?

Comment: @FlorianVuillemot Yes right, the nodepool does cale out a bit but not to the extend that it can handle the full load.
We are running a loadtest on our system and this loadtest triggers our HorizontalPodAutoscaling for 2 deployments. They quickly reach the scale threshhold and then they deploy new pods which are then in pending state since not enough resources are available (nodes).
Our loadtest runs for about 1,5h and at roughtly 1h it reaches 11 nodes quite good but after that it is stuck at 11 even though we have about 100pods in pending state.

Comment: Have you examined your quotas? Are they high enough?

Comment: If you use Azure CNI, do you have enough IPs available in your VNET?

Comment: @FlorianVuillemot 
Yes, we have checked the quotas and there is plenty of room.
And yes, we are using Azure CNI with the nodes beeing placed inside of a /20 network so there is also plenty of IP space left (about 3400 free ones at the moment).
When we predefine the pod count we can see that the cluster is scaling out fine. Only the combination with the HPA is not working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [virtual nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/virtual-nodes) to handle bursts better.

> To rapidly scale application workloads in an AKS cluster, you can use
> virtual nodes. With virtual nodes, you have quick provisioning of
> pods, and only pay per second for their execution time. You don't need
> to wait for Kubernetes cluster autoscaler to deploy VM compute nodes
> to run more pods. Virtual nodes are only supported with Linux pods and
> nodes.